# Allowing both inline viewing and downloading of s3 hosted images

Tags: amazon-s3, content-disposition

I understand that when using s3 that images with the inline content-disposition will display in the browser, and images with the attachment content-disposition will be downloaded. What I'm hoping is that it's possible to allow the image to be displayed inline when loaded directly, but that it's also possible to have a download link that will cause it to be downloaded if clicked. More specifically, if I have a jpeg image with the following settings in S3:

```
Content-Disposition     attachment
SystContent-Type        image/jpeg
```

Then it will download whenever loaded directly. If I remove the Content-Disposition, or set it to inline, it will show up in the browser.

For example, let's say my site is domain.com, and I've setup my s3 bucket to be images.domain.com (with a CNAME). I'd like a link from domain.com such as:

```
<a href="https://images.example.com/picture.jpg" download>Download</a>
```

which would download the image, but if I simply load https://images.example.com/picture.jpg directly in the browser, it would be displayed inline in the browser.

As above, I've tried the download attribute for html links, but it doesn't seem to be working in my case. I noticed some browsers only support same-origin download links (such as Chrome and Firefox) but I was wondering if this was something I could fix with CORS config of the s3 bucket. I tried allowing origin from my main site in the CORS config, but it didn't seem to help. I set up the bucket with the following CORS settings:

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "PUT",
        "POST",
        "DELETE"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "https://example.com"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
},
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
}
```

]

I also tried using Safari to try a download link, and it didn't work either (assuming Safari didn't become stricter about CORS content).

Any ideas on how to create a download link for s3 images that do not have an attachment content-disposition? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70082262/aws-s3-automatically-change-response-header claims you can change the headers if you use a presigned URL

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the url query parameter in the view link.

https://images.example.com/picture.jpg?response-content-disposition=inline

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).