# AWS S3 - automatically change response header

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, response-headers

Our team is building a web app that allows users to download video files. We currently host our files on AWS S3, but since our site doesn't reside on AWS, we can't use `<a href="blah">` to prompt download. If we use that html element, users simply get redirected to a video player - which is fine, but Safari on mobile doesn't allow for users to download the video file via the video player.

We found that manually setting the file's content disposition to attachment on S3 works, but we have not found a way to automate that. We tried adding a content-disposition: attachment key-value pairing in our payload, which works, but adds a "User defined" meta data in the form of `x-amz-meta-content-disposition`, which doesn't work as the file could not be downloaded as an attachment. It seems only "System defined" works.

Has anyone ever encountered this issue before and found a workaround?

[see screenshot for what I'm referencing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMw0n.png)

Comment: Is web hosting enabled on the S3 bucket with the videos? AWS might apply the right mime types if it is?

Comment: Our website is built on top of Bubble.io's no-code platform, which I believe sits in AWS Oregon. We don't have management access to our workloads. Our video files sit in AWS S3 Singapore on our own account because we're in Asia. 

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: You could try enable web hosting on your S3 bucket in SIngapore. Not 100% sure it will work, but it may be a way to have AWS deliver your videos in a compatible way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion JBS, we enabled it, but it still isn't working...

Answer (score 1):

You can set the content disposition when the file is created.

This is done by uploading the file via a presigned url.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html for details on the presigned urls.

Alternatively you can use a presigned url to return to get the file from S3 and override the content disposition header on the GET request.